# How to set mode hook with lambda using use-package

Tags: hooks, use-package

I'm attempting to set the following hook using `use-package`, but it's not getting applied.

Normal elisp:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
```

Using `use-package`:

```lisp
(use-package org-bullets
  :ensure t
  :after org-plus-contrib
  :hook (org-mode . (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1))))
```

What's the correct way to do this with `use-package :hook`?

Answer (score 4):

You need remove `:after org-plus-contrib`, it's preventing your `:hook ...` from running.

---

By the way, consider replacing

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
```

with

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-bullets-mode)
```

unless you really need support Emacs 23 or older versions (see also https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.24#L3303). With `use-package`, you can use

```
(use-package org-bullets
  :ensure t
  :hook (org-mode . org-bullets-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the new link. Why is the :after preventing the :hook? I want the :after to express the fact that org-bullets needs the org package to be installed.

Comment: @retrodev That :after means `(with-eval-after-load 'org-plus-contrib (add-hook ...))`, however, there is no such feature `org-plus-contrib` at all, thus `add-hook` will never run. Besides, `add-hook` will always work even if the hook is void for now, see [`(info "(elisp) Setting Hooks")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Hooks.html) if you don't understand. Besides, you should understand why you need :after in the first place.